# Skip list of filenames from txt file with os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to upload files that users dump into a shared folder to an FTP site. Only certain files must be uploaded based on a pattern in the filename, and that works. I would like to avoid uploading files that have been uploaded in the past. A simple solution would be to move the files to a subdirectory once uploaded, but users whish for the files to remain where they are.

I was thinking of writing a filename to a text file when each iteration of the loops makes an update. Populating the text file works.

Excluding directories with os.walk is mentioned in many articles and I can get that to work fine, but excluding a list of filenames seems to be a bit more obscure

This is what I have so far:

```
import ftplib
import os
import os.path
import fnmatch

## set local path variables
dir = 'c:/Temp'
hist_path = 'C:/Temp/hist.txt'

pattern = '*SomePattern*'

## make the ftp connection and set appropriate working directory
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.someserver.com')
ftp.login('someuser', 'somepassword')
ftp.cwd('somedirectory')

## make a list of previously uploaded files
hist_list = open(hist_path, 'r')
hist_content = hist_list.read()
# print(hist_content)

## loop through the files and upload them to the FTP as above
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for fname in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): # this filters for filenames that include the pattern

        ## upload each file to the ftp
        os.chdir(dir)
        full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + fname, open(full_fname, 'rb'))

        ## add an entry for each file into the historical uploads log
        f = open(hist_path, 'a')
        f.write(fname + '\n')
        f.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can't files be renamed, such as - append some text like 'uploaded' to each file name. This can help to avoid FTP'ing files with that string in its name. So all files are still in original location with just a small change in name.

Comment: I would just write all of the fs/directory traversal logic myself and not even bother with `os.walk()` would an example of that be helpful? or are you set on using `os.walk`?

Comment: Yes I would like to look at an example  @alexpdev

Comment: @Pankaj that is a good idea

Comment: @opperman.eric if Pankaj suggestion works for you then I would also recommend that. It is a much simpler